# How to find which points lay inside an area marked by outer points?

Tags: r, vector, 2d

I need to interpolate a in 3D and I want to do this only for the area where I actually have observed `x` and `y` values. This can be done in the following steps:

1. Find outer points of the 2d x and y area (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934933/how-to-find-outer-points-in-2-vectors)).
2. Create a grid for interpolation but keep only grid points that lay inside the outer points of step 1.
3. Interpolate.

Here an example:

[image: Plot]

In the first step I found out the outer points of the observed data (here observed data as big black points and the outer points in red). In a second step I generated a grid (small black points). Now I need to know which grid points lay inside the outer points area (which I here marked by connecting the red points with a red line). How to find those grid points?

Code and data

```
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol= 2))
library(ggplot2)
grid_df <- expand.grid(seq(min(df$X1), max(df$X1), length.out= 100),
                       seq(min(df$X2), max(df$X2), length.out= 100))

df$outer <- FALSE
df$outer[chull(df$X1, df$X2)] <- TRUE

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data= df, mapping= aes(X1, X2)) +
  geom_point(data= df[df$outer, ], mapping= aes(X1, X2), col= "red") +
  geom_point(data= grid_df, mapping= aes(Var1, Var2), col= "black", size= .5)
```

Expected output is a third column in `grid_df` which is `TRUE` if the point lays inside the area. **I look for a R base solution.**

Comment: This may help you: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/geometry/html/inhulln.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with base R using axis rotation.

Imagine that the area borders would be the x and y axis:

[image: Rotation idea]

Now it is easy to exclude grid points outside the area: We just need to exclude points that lay above the new x axis. We need to repead this for all the area borders and then we know what grid points to exclude.

The code for this:

```
# Data as in question (just variable names changed).
set.seed(3)
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol= 2)), c("x", "y"))
library(ggplot2)
grid_df <- setNames(expand.grid(seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), length.out= 100),
                            seq(min(df$y), max(df$y), length.out= 100)), c("x", "y"))

# Create dataframe with border points (rbind to connect the last with the
# first points).
border <- rbind.data.frame(df[chull(x= df), ],
                       df[chull(x= df), ][1, ])

# See for every border whether grid points are outside.
grid_outside <- sapply(2:nrow(border), function(row_i){
  # Extract one border line.
  border_i <- border[(row_i-1):row_i, ]
  # See what points must lay inside the area.
  point_inside <- data.frame(x= median(df$x),
                         y= median(df$y))
  # Find slope of the border line.
  slope <- diff(border_i$y)/diff(border_i$x)
  # Calculate angle from slope.
  angle <- atan(slope)*(180/pi)
  angle <- ifelse(angle < 0, angle + 180, angle)
  # Rotating function.
  rotate <- function(data, angle){
    data.frame(x= data$x * cos(angle* pi / 180) + data$y * sin(angle* pi / 180),
               y= -data$x * sin(angle* pi / 180) + data$y * cos(angle* pi / 180))
  }
  # Rotate the data.  
  border_new_i <- rotate(data= border_i, angle= angle)
  grid_df_new <- rotate(data= grid_df, angle= angle)
  point_inside_new <- rotate(point_inside, angle= angle)
  # Depending on rotation results inner area is under or over
  # the new border point y. Define outside grid points accordingly.
  if(border_new_i$y[1] < point_inside_new$y){
    outside_border_i <- grid_df_new$y < border_new_i$y[1]
  } else{
    outside_border_i <- grid_df_new$y > border_new_i$y[1]
  }

  outside_border_i
})
# Is a row outside the area according to one of the border?
grid_outside <- rowSums(grid_outside) >= 1
# Show points inside area.
grid_df_inside <- grid_df[!grid_outside, ]
```

For the data in the question the resulting plot is:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data= df, mapping= aes(x, y)) +
  geom_path(data= border, mapping= aes(x, y), col= "red") +
  geom_point(data= grid_df, mapping= aes(x, y), col= "black", size= .5) +
  geom_point(data= grid_df_inside, mapping= aes(x, y), col= "green", size= .5)
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Great answer! +1

Comment: Perhaps it is faster to use `geometry::inhulln`, since it appears to be written in C.

Comment: @PaulS I write a package and try to avoid additional packages. Speed seems okay for the code in answer to me..

Comment: That is OK, @PuckFutin! Since you are creating a package, that makes sense: to avoid dependencies.